# Parameter names in Python functions that take single object or iterable

Tags: python, naming-conventions

I have some functions in my code that accept either an object or an iterable of objects as input. I was taught to use meaningful names for everything, but I am not sure how to comply here. What should I call a parameter that can a sinlge object or an iterable of objects? I have come up with two ideas, but I don't like either of them:

1. `FooOrManyFoos` - This expresses what goes on, but I could imagine that someone not used to it could have trouble understanding what it means right away
2. `param` - Some generic name. This makes clear that it can be several things, but does explain nothing about what the parameter is used for.

Normally I call iterables of objects just the plural of what I would call a single object. I know this might seem a little bit compulsive, but Python is supposed to be (among others) about readability.

Comment: Must you accept a single object, instead of an iterable of one object? That would make your code much clearer (i.e., pass `[foo]` instead of `foo`).

Comment: @katrielalex: This is possible. I have a C++ background and I am used to using overloads for this kind of problem. Maybe I have some rethinking to do here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have some functions in my code that accept either an object or an iterable of objects as input.

This is a very exceptional and often very bad thing to do.  It's trivially avoidable.

i.e., pass [foo] instead of foo when calling this function.

The only time you can justify doing this is when (1) you have an installed base of software that expects one form (iterable or singleton) and (2) you have to expand it to support the other use case.  So.  You **only** do this when expanding an existing function that has an existing code base.

If this is new development, Do Not Do This.

> I have come up with two ideas, but I don't like either of them:

[Only two?]

> FooOrManyFoos - This expresses what goes on, but I could imagine that someone not used to it could have trouble understanding what it means right away

What?  Are you saying you provide NO other documentation, and no other training?  No support?  No advice?   Who is the "someone not used to it"?  Talk to them.  Don't assume or imagine things about them.

Also, don't use Leading Upper Case Names.

> param - Some generic name. This makes clear that it can be several things, but does explain nothing about what the parameter is used for.

Terrible.  Never. Do. This.

I looked in the Python library for examples.  Most of the functions that do this have simple descriptions.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#isinstance

isinstance(object, classinfo)

They call it "classinfo" and it can be a class or a tuple of classes.

You could do that, too.

You **must** consider the common use case and the exceptions.  Follow the 80/20 rule.

1. 80% of the time, you can replace this with an iterable and not have this problem.
2. In the remaining 20% of the cases, you have an installed base of software built around an assumption (either iterable or single item) and you need to add the other case.  Don't change the name, just change the documentation.  If it used to say "foo" it still says "foo" but you make it accept an iterable of "foo's" without making any change to the parameters.  If it used to say "foo_list" or "foo_iter", then it still says "foo_list" or "foo_iter" but it will quietly tolerate a singleton without breaking.

   - 80% of the code is the legacy ("foo" or "foo_list")
   - 20% of the code is the new feature ("foo" can be an iterable or "foo_list" can be a single object.)

Answer (score 4):

I guess I'm a little late to the party, but I'm suprised that nobody suggested a decorator.

```
def withmany(f):
    def many(many_foos):
        for foo in many_foos:
            yield f(foo)
    f.many = many
    return f

@withmany
def process_foo(foo):
    return foo + 1


processed_foo = process_foo(foo)

for processed_foo in process_foo.many(foos):
    print processed_foo
```

I saw a similar pattern in one of Alex Martelli's posts but I don't remember the link off hand.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you're agonizing over the ugliness of code like:

```
def ProcessWidget(widget_thing):
  # Infer if we have a singleton instance and make it a
  # length 1 list for consistency
  if isinstance(widget_thing, WidgetType):
    widget_thing = [widget_thing]

  for widget in widget_thing:
    #...
```

My suggestion is to avoid overloading your interface to handle two distinct cases.  I tend to write code that favors re-use and clear naming of methods over clever dynamic use of parameters:

```
def ProcessOneWidget(widget):
  #...

def ProcessManyWidgets(widgets):
  for widget in widgets:
    ProcessOneWidget(widget)
```

Often, I start with this simple pattern, but then have the opportunity to optimize the "Many" case when there are efficiencies to gain that offset the additional code complexity and partial duplication of functionality.  If this convention seems overly verbose, one can opt for names like "ProcessWidget" and "ProcessWidgets", though the difference between the two is a single easily missed character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *args magic (varargs) to make your params always be iterable.

Pass a single item or multiple known items as normal function args like **func(arg1, arg2, ...)** and pass iterable arguments with an asterisk before, like **func(*args)**

Example:

```
# magic *args function
def foo(*args):
    print args

# many ways to call it
foo(1)
foo(1, 2, 3)

args1 = (1, 2, 3)
args2 = [1, 2, 3]
args3 = iter((1, 2, 3))

foo(*args1)
foo(*args2)
foo(*args3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you name your parameter in a very high-level way?  people who read the code are more interested in knowing what the parameter represents ("clients") than what their type is ("list_of_tuples"); the type can be defined in the function documentation string, which is a good thing since it might change, in the future (the type is sometimes an implementation detail).

Comment: My problem here is that something like `clients` suggests several objects. If a caller wants to pass a single object only, he may think he needs to wrap it into some iterable (that would be my intuition). I am looking for a way to express that single object is fine too.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: I would give up indicating the parameter type in the parameter name, and include this information early in the documentation string.  After all, you often *have* to call a list like `file_lines` even when you know that this list might contain only one line.  Nobody will expect you to call it `file_line_or_file_lines`.  So, I would suggest that your code will be perfectly legible if you use a short and high-level, descriptive name.  :)

Answer (score 1):

I would do 1 thing,

```
def myFunc(manyFoos):
    if not type(manyFoos) in (list,tuple):
        manyFoos = [manyFoos]
    #do stuff here
```

so then you don't need to worry anymore about its name.

in a function you should try to achieve to have 1 action, accept the same parameter type and return the same type.

Instead of filling the functions with ifs you could have 2 functions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't care exactly what kind of iterable you get, you could try to get an iterator for the parameter using iter(). If iter() raises a TypeError exception, the parameter is not iterable, so you then create a list or tuple of the one item, which is iterable and Bob's your uncle.

```
def doIt(foos):
    try:
        iter(foos)
    except TypeError:
        foos = [foos]
    for foo in foos:
        pass    # do something here
```

The only problem with this approach is if foo is a string. A string is iterable, so passing in a single string rather than a list of strings will result in iterating over the characters in a string. If this is a concern, you could add an if test for it. At this point it's getting wordy for boilerplate code, so I'd break it out into its own function.

```
def iterfy(iterable):
    if isinstance(iterable, basestring):
        iterable = [iterable]
    try:
        iter(iterable)
    except TypeError:
        iterable = [iterable]
    return iterable

def doIt(foos):
    for foo in iterfy(foos):
        pass    # do something
```

Unlike some of those answering, I like doing this, since it eliminates one thing the caller could get wrong when using your API. "Be conservative in what you generate but liberal in what you accept."

To answer your original question, i.e. what you should name the parameter, I would still go with "foos" even though you will accept a single item, since your *intent* is to accept a list.  If it's not iterable, that is *technically* a mistake, albeit one you will correct for the caller since processing just the one item is probably what they want. Also, if the caller *thinks* they must pass in an iterable even of one item, well, that will of course work fine and requires very little syntax, so why worry about correcting their misapprehension?

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a name explaining that the parameter can be an instance or a list of instances. Say  `one_or_more_Foo_objects`. I find it better than the bland `param`.

Answer (score -1):

I'm working on a fairly big project now and we're passing maps around and just calling our parameter `map`. The map contents vary depending on the function that's being called. This probably isn't the best situation, but we reuse a lot of the same code on the maps, so copying and pasting is easier.

I would say instead of naming it what it is, you should name it what it's used for. Also, just be careful that you can't call use `in` on a not iterable.

Comment: `map` being defined by Python itself, this is a potentially confusing choice as a parameter name: people expect `map` to mean Python's `map`.

Comment: Agree with what @EOL said. It is a good idea to avoid using names of built-in functions as parameter names.

Comment: I don't mean I completely reuse code by copy-pasting. Like I said, it's probably not the best solution. My second paragraph was more my answer.